# How to extract just the URL from string with doesn't contains the "http" or "https" and remove it

Tags: php, regex

I have a form with multiple text fields.

I want to get rid of all links in the user's input (whether starting with `http(s)` or not).

For example:

> Hello guys, please check my website: **http://www.example.com/page.php?id=5**,
>   here is my facebook page **http://facebook.com/home** and my twitter **www.twitter.com/home**

I would like to get rid of all the links, here is what I've tried so far:

```
$userInput = preg_replace("/\S+\.\S+/", "", $userInput);
```

It works but it also removes words like `P.H.P`.

It also fails if the user doesn't add a whitespace after link.

How do I edit my RegEx to achieve my requirements?

Comment: If you're talking about *links*, then you should use an XML parser and look for `<a>` tags. If you're talking about *strings that look like URLs but don't start with http*, then you can't really reliably do that, especially given the ridiculous number of top-level domains nowadays. Just about anybody writing a sentence without a space following a dot will trip your detector. "i like html design.blog templating is my specialty."

Comment: Yes exactly. I'm having a hard time figuring it out. So is there any solution?

Comment: _"So is there any solution?"_ There is no 100% solution. Anything you implement will be wrong some of the time. You have to decide which is better for your needs -- leaving the URLs alone, or maybe editing them wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
(?:https?://)?\w{3,}\.\S+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/mSYCaO/3/), this may need some fiddling though.

---

Broken down:

```
(?:https?://)? # http:// or https://, both are optional
\w{3,}         # at least three word characters
\.             # a dot
\S+            # not a whitespace, 1+
```

---

In `PHP`:

```
$new_string = preg_replace('~?:https?://)?\w{3,}\.\S+~', '', $your_string_here);
```

Comment: If I put the word "Please" just after the full stop (without space) then it grabs that word too :/ https://regex101.com/r/mSYCaO/4

Comment: @ZahidSaeed: Yup. You need to provide more example strings then.

Comment: Can you try out with the current one?

Comment: @ZahidSaeed: See the comment from Alex under your original question - that's the exact problem here. You might get 90-95% but not all.